# SQL Sever Management Studio for SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000, ssms

We use mostly SQL Server 2005 but have a few SQL Server 2000 servers laying around. Is there a SQL Server Management Studio like application for SQL Server 2000?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 Management Tools includes Enterprise Manager (like Management Studio), Query Analizer (a tool to execute scripts) and Profiler (a tool to profile queries).

And you **can** connect and work in your SQL Management Studio 2005 with SQL Server 2000 :)

Or you can use [EMS SQL Manager](http://sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/manager) if you want something different.

Comment: Agreed, just use SQL Management Studio, connects just fine.

Comment: The exception is if you have DTS pacakges, you need a special download form Microsoft to see them and I find them easier to work with in Enterprise Manager because EM lets me open multiples and SSMS won't even let me run a query if I am looking at a DTS package.

Comment: Here is a link to Management Studio 2005 (you can't download Enterprise Manager) : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961

Answer (score 5):

In SQL 2000, you can use Enterpise Manager to browse objects and perform many administrative tasks.  You can use SQL Query Analyzer to write and run SQL, view query execution plans, etc.  SQL Profiler can be used to profile queries.

However, you can use the SQL 2005 version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect to SQL 2000 servers and it works great.

Comment: Should you choose to install EM and QA, I find it works better if they are installed first and then SQL Server 2005 (and/or 2008). For various reasons I have all three and it only worked when I installed them in order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It comes shipped with SQL Server 2000 and is called Enterprise Manager. It does not do everything SQL Server Management Studio does though (ie. like let you run queries - you have to use Query Analyzer for that).

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to SQL 2000 though, so why not just use that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the management tools that actually shipped with SQL Server 2000 were:

[SQL Server 2000 Query Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945%28SQL.80%29.aspx), [SQL Server 2000 Query Designer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179698.aspx), [SQL Server 2000 Profiler](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3482216/Introduction-to-SQL-Profiler.htm) & [SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215396%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

The Enterprise Manager was the main management tool used to create & edit databases and schemas, stored procedures etc. and the Query Analyser tool was effectively the same as the Query Window in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio.

It's completely fine, however, to use the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio to administer and configure SQL Server 2000 database servers.

Answer (score 0):

I use the sql server management studio 2005 tools on our sql 2000 server instances.  We have licenses for both servers, and I found those tools easier to use than the old enterprise manager tools that come with sql 2000

Answer (score 0):

There was a tool called [DBAMgr2K](http://www.asql.biz/DbaMgr.shtm) which was extensive and did the job nicely and will handle SQL Server 2000 if you do not have SQL Management tools.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.